# Porting of Windows 7 desktop application to Windows 7 tablet

Tags: windows, windows-7, porting, tablet

I have developed an application on desktop Windows 7 now I want to run it on Windows 7 tablet.

Is there any difference between Windows 7 desktop OS and Windows 7 tablet OS? If yes, what is it?

What steps do I need to take in order to port my application?

Comment: You might want to make your application more "touch" friendly, but the application should run unchanged. Windows 7 doesn't have a "tablet" version, unlike XP, which did.

Comment: thanks for help!! I have another question. As per my knowledge, Windows tablets come with Windows 7 OS. IS there any other Window OS flavour compatible with tablet?

Comment: Correct, tablets come with Windows 7. I just mean there is no special version of Windows 7 for tablets. If the app works on a PC, it will work in a tablet.

Comment: Note. If you want to run on tablets "friendly" - take care of controls dimensions. Small buttons and links very hard to deal with fingers.